# Output from running Matlab (Linux) as a Cron job in Bash includes many ">>" in the email

Tags: bash, matlab, cron

I am running a Matlab script on Linux (RedHat Enterprise Linux RHEL 7.6, 64-bit) as a cron job. I am not admin on that machine, therefore, I use `crontab -e` to schedule the job. The installed version of Matlab is 2018b. The email which I recieve upon execution includes a couple of `>>` at the beginning and end which I find a bit irritating.

Here, an example of the email:

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.

                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2018 The MathWorks, Inc.
                   R2018b (9.5.0.944444) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                              August 28, 2018

 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
 
>> >> >> >> 
Matlab started: 2020-07-31 21:50:26.
>> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> >> 
Going to update from 2015-01-01 00:00:00 UTC to 2015-12-31 23:00:00 UTC. 

[...]

>> Matlab closes: 2020-07-31 23:26:41. 
>>
```

The corresponding lines at the beginning of the Matlab script look exactly like this:

```
close all
clearvars
% profile on % to check performance
fprintf('\nMatlab started: %s.\n', char(datetime()))

%% Database user parameters
% connects always to the soecified database on "localhost"
DB_conn_name = 'abc';
DB_username = 'def';
DB_password = 'ghi';

% Add path and subfolders
if isunix
    addpath(genpath('/project/abc'));
elseif ispc
    addpath(genpath('C:\Branches\abc'));
end

% Change working folder
if isunix
    cd /project/abc
elseif ispc
    cd C:\Branches\abc
end

% Add database driver to path
javaaddpath JDBC_driver/mysql-connector-java.jar % Forward slashes within Matlab work even on Windows

% Set default datetime format
datetime.setDefaultFormats('default','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')


%% Begin and end of update period
% now_UTC = datetime('now','TimeZone','UTC');
% time_2 = datetime(now_UTC.Year, now_UTC.Month, now_UTC.Day-1, 22, 0, 0); % Set the end time not too late, otherwise, some data might not yet be available for some areas leading to ugly "dips" in Power BI.

% During each update, we update e.g. the past 30 days
% datetime_month_delay = time_1 - days(30);

% Override automatic dates obtained below, for testing purposes
% time_1 = datetime(2020,1,1,0,0,0);
% time_2 = datetime(2020,2,1,23,0,0);

% Updating several years, one at a time
for iYear = 2015:2019
    time_1 = datetime(iYear,1,1,0,0,0);
    time_2 = datetime(iYear,12,31,23,0,0);

    fprintf(['\nGoing to update from ',char(time_1),' UTC to ',char(time_2),' UTC. \n'])

[...]
```

Looks as though each row that is outside the `for` loop produces an empty line and therefore such a `>>` prompt in the output. Also visible at the end (not included here).

The `crontab -e` looks like the following:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=<my email address>
HOME=/project/abc
HTTP_PROXY=<proxy address>:8086
HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy address>:8086

# Run script regularly: minute hour day month dayofweek command
# No linebreaks allowed

15 2 * * * ~/script.sh
```

The shell script `script.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/prog/matlab2018b/bin/matlab -nodesktop < ~/git-repos/abc/matlabscript.m
```

Does anyone have an idea what I need to change to get rid of these `>>`? That would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `matlab -nodesktop -r scriptname` to run the script (no .m appended). You need to start MATLAB in the script directory. Otherwise use `run('script.m')`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Your solution **works fine** in combination with the `-sd` option in order to set the script folder:`matlab -r scriptname -sd <path to script folder>`. The `-nodesktop` flag does not seem to be necessary with the `-r`option. Thanks!

Comment: But do make sure your script ends with `exit`. I presume it already does, otherwise your previous solution would leave MATLAB open as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-nodesktop` flag is still giving you an interactive shell, which is why crontab is capturing the prompts at all.  You need to tell the matlab command what statement to execute.

I know you are using R2018b; but, I am going to give you BOTH answers for before and after R2019a, in case you ever upgrade.

For both answers: Because you called this in your crontab, make sure to use full path for your MATLAB executable for security reasons; and, it would be good to make sure you use the -sd flag as well so that your statement to execute is first in the path.  The statement to execute is to be typed the same way you would type it on the MATLABcommand line.

**Before R2019a**: Per the doc page for the [R2018b matlab (Linux) command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html?), you need to run your command with the `-r` and `-sd` flags together.  The `-sd` flag specifies your startup directory.  Also, your code needs to have an exit statement at the end so that the matlab executable knows its done.

```
/path/before_R2019a/matlab -sd /path/startup_directory -b statement
```

**Starting in R2019a**, the `-batch` flag in your invocation of MATLAB is the recommended way to run automated jobs like this, per the [matlab (Linux) command doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html)

Note that starting in R2019a, the `-r` flag is **NOT recommended**; and, it **should NOT be used with the `-batch` flag**.

The `-batch` flag is simpler to use, and was added to make automation tasks easier. For starters, you no longer need to have an exit statement in your code with this approach.

Also remember that if you need quotes, starting in R2016b, MATLAB handles both double and single quoted strings.  Choose appropriately in your script or cron call to handle your linux shell replacements - or avoid them.

```
/path/R2019a+/matlab -sd /path/startup_directory -b statement
```

As an added bonus, if you use the `-batch` flag, you can tell from inside your script whether it is running from a `-batch` call or interactively using the MATLAB variable [`batchStartupOptionUsed`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/batchstartupoptionused.html).